# Override 3rd Party Embedded Resource

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I'm using the Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms control in an MVC3 application.  The ReportViewer gets it's javascript by calling an HttpHandler in that same assembly.  That handler returns the javascript that is stored as an embedded resource.

My problem is that the javascript that it returns has a bug that causes runtime errors in firefox under certain scenarios.

I'd like to override the embedded resource being returned to use my corrected javascript.

How would I go about doing this?  I've looked at resx files, but I don't know how the file should be named, where it would go, etc...

Answer (score 0):

If you know the bug, you could just change the function yourself.

```
function iHaveBug() { alert('buggy'); }
```

Then you come in and over write it after it has been loaded:

```
iHaveBug = function() { alert('all better'); }
```

Comment: My problem is that the control renders the ui, makes the call to the handler to get the dynamic javascipt, then makes calls to the returned javascript functions all within it's lifecycle.  From what I can tell, there isn't a place for me to step in and change things between when it requests the javascript and when it makes calls to the functions as they are all part of one operation.  It's not loading a file, then later some user event triggers the call.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to rebuild the assembly with the corrected javascript file, which is not as hard as it sounds. This post tells you how to do it:  http://fortheloveofcode.wordpress.com/2007/09/24/change-resources-inside-assembly/

Comment: Actually I did try that before, using that same post.  The problem I ran into was that the assembly is signed (it's from MSFT afterall), so I can't rebuild it and re-sign it.  When I removed the signing (using the snremove tool), disassembled, changed my javascript, and then reassembled, I started getting runtime errors about how "Dispose() is in a security neutral but contained in security critical type" or something similar (I don't recall exactly).  At that point I figured I was barking up the wrong tree and changed directions to try to override the resource value via config files.